# Does anyone know a method to branch work items in Polarion ALM

Tags: alm

In specific, I would like to maintain a baseline set of requirement work items but also develop a second subset of slightly modified requirements for a related product without 'copying' them to a second project.

Answer (score 2):

In Polarion 2012 you can actually branch whole document with those workitems. I guess that's feature exactly for you.

See what is new here http://blog.polarion.com/archives/1922